# Executing threads (not thread groups) in JMeter sequentially

Tags: jmeter

I have a Thread Group with the following property:

```
Number of Threads (users): 5
```

Now, when I run, all 5 threads launch concurrently.

Is there any setting or config element I can use to execute one thread at a time? In other words, I would like to execute Thread 2 only after Thread 1 has completed execution.

I believe the "Run Thread Groups consecutively..." option applies to "Thread Groups" and not to Threads.

[image]

Comment: Any feedback on this ? If ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that it's helpful to others, thx

Answer (score 2):

1) you can use a Critical Section controller that will ensure only one thread runs at a time( put all your samples as its children)

2) you can play with rampup

3) you can set only one thread, and use loop iteration to 5